# Count number of times value appears in column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, count

Tried looking everywhere for this but my searching hasn't given me any answers.
Looking to count how many times the word 'Sydney' comes up in the column 'Suburb'

```
CustomerId  FirstName   LastName    StreetAddress   Suburb  PostCode
C001    James           Smith       400 Kent St     Sydney      2000
C002    Maria           Carpenter   333 Smith St    Westmead    2145
C003    Dennis          Miller      214 Uni Rd      Sydney      2000
```

I want it to provide an outcome like:

```
numCustomersFromSydney
                    2
```

Comment: select count(*) from urtable where suburb='Sydney';

Comment: or if you want substring then `where suburb LIKE '%Sydney%`, this is a fairly simple query you can easily get it by googling.

Comment: Everywhere? Really? Not convinced;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this simple query:

```
select count(*) as numCustomersFromSydney from table where Suburb = "Sydney";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT() and an alias name:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Suburb) AS numCustomersFromSydney
FROM
    yourtable
WHERE
    Suburb = 'Sydney'
```