# How to put result of COUNT to a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I found this question [Count number of times value appears in column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009111/count-number-of-times-value-appears-in-column-in-mysql) and I want to tie up to it. I want to put the result of the query into a variable. I tried

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM myTable WHERE town = 'Sydney'");
echo $sql;
```

But this will echo whole command, not the result (which should be 2)
Any ideas on this?

Comment: I am not sure about mysql functions, you shouldn't use them, they are outdated, but in PHP PDO you have to execute the query

Comment: This is no different to any other query that you might want to run; you run the query, then go through the result set that the database returns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use mysql_num_rows(). Something like this.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE town = 'Sydney'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo $count;
```

mysql_num_rows — Get number of rows in result

OR with COUNT() mysql function

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM myTable WHERE town = 'Sydney'");
while($rw=mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
    echo $count = $rw->count;
    }
```

Comment: You can, but if there are a couple of million rows in the database, you'll select them all and then count them. What's wrong with just running `SELECT COUNT(*)`? That way, you're just getting a single row, and letting the database do all the counting for you.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM myTable WHERE town = 'Sydney'